# How to make the text display the same in a ng-model from a select with ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I am new to angular (problem one). I am trying to tie the formatted text from a select with ng-options to the ng-model that is being called in the page.  What happens is the below take language codes like en-US and changes the text to English, which displays in the select perfectly.  When I use {{ textSelect }} it displays as en-US.  So how do I get it to display correctly?

```
<select ng-model="textSelect" ng-options="language.code as language.name for language in availableLanguages"></select>

<p>{{ textSelect }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="textSelect" 
        ng-options="language as language.name for language in availableLanguages"></select>

<p>{{ textSelect.name }}</p>
```

Is one suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing language.code to language?

Comment: I guess you could create a filter which does the opposite of what your ng-options is doing (matching selected "name" against "code"). But that would be ugly to say the least.. :)